# POM.xml (dependency related)

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

I tried downloading the most updated `selenium webdriver` from `seleniumhq` via `Maven` using the dependency present over there. The version is `3.0.1`. But once I have downloaded the jar files into my project the `POM.xml` throws error and isn't compatible. But it is working fine for the earlier version of the `selenium webdriver i.e 2.53.1`.

Is there a specific reason why this should be happening in my project?

Comment: could you post actual pom.xml? and the URL from which you downloaded?

Comment: <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>               This is the dependency that I have used and the url from which I downloaded this is http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp

Comment: could you please also share the screenshot of the error? I don't see any issues in the `pom.xml`. Did you execute tests? Any errors while developing/executing?